# How can we mock test IntegrationFlow in spring boot. I am using Spring Integration inside a Spring boot app using Spring Integration File

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a task where I need to implement IntegrationFlow in Spring boot app and for that I created one project. Below are 3 classes.

**IntegrationConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Transformer transformer;

   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {

       return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReader(),spec -> spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(500)))
       .transform(transformer,"transform")
       .handle(fileWriter())
       .get();

}



@Bean
   public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWriter() {

   FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("destination"));
   handler.setExpectReply(false);
   return handler;
}



@Bean
   public FileReadingMessageSource fileReader() {

   FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
   source.setDirectory(new File("source"));
   return source;
}
```

}

**Transformer.java**

```
@Component
   public class Transformer {

   public String transform(String filePath) throws IOException {

   String content = new String (Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
   return "Transformed: " + content;
}
```

}

**SpringIntegrationExample.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
   public class SpringIntegrationExample {

   public static void main(String[] args){
   SpringApplication.run(SpringIntegrationExample.class,args);
}
}
```

Now there is task to mock tests this.

I am new to test and not sure how to test this using either JUnit or Mockito or both.
I tried with JUnit with When().thenReturn() but not able to test IntegrationFlow in that.

Can anyone help me on this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple notes for your configuration so far:

The `FileReadingMessageSource` produces `File` as payload for messages.
The `FileWritingMessageHandler` can deal with `File` payloads.
Therefore you don't need that `transform()` in between.

Although you just show not the whole flow...

There is Java DSL-specific factory for fluent API: `org.springframework.integration.file.dsl.Files`.

It is not clear what you'd like to mock, but here is a dedicated documentation about testing with Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing

Comment: The main thing I am trying to achieve is to somehow demonstrate mock test IntegrationFlow. Like, first create flow using IntegrationFlow and then mock it using test case. I will have a look at the documentation you shared. Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason in mocking an `IntegrationFlow`. It is just logical container for integration components with no real time value. It is better to look into mocking those individual components which are doing a real job producing or handling messages.